# Flutter textformfield validation with firebase database

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I am new to flutter and i am working on a result processing and record keeping system in the result processing part i have a form that takes in some details about the students like session, level, course code(It's for a university). now i have a collection in firebase of the levels and sessions in the department i am using for a case study and would like to check that the lecturer input corresponds or matches what is in the database.I am using a textformfield but i don't know how to validate the input with what is in firebase database. This is my code for the form. Thanks in advance for the help

```
    class ScoreSheetPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<ScoreSheetPage> createState() => _ScoreSheetPageState();
    }
    
    class _ScoreSheetPageState extends State<ScoreSheetPage> {
      final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      TextEditingController currentSession = TextEditingController();
    
      TextEditingController currentLevelYear = TextEditingController();
    
      TextEditingController matriculationNumber = TextEditingController();
    
      TextEditingController currentSemester = TextEditingController();
    
      TextEditingController courseCode = TextEditingController();
    
      TextEditingController studentMarks1 = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController studentMarks2 = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController studentMarks3 = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController studentMarks4 = TextEditingController();
    
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 230,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF363f93)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: Text(
                                "RHEMA UNIVERSITY RESULT CALCULATION SYSTEM",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: kHeading,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Welcome",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: kHeading,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Form(
                          key: formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Please fill in the required information",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF363f93),
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.04,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: currentSession,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText:
                                        "Enter current session, use format(1234-1234)"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4})+$')
                                          .hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct session number";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.04,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: currentLevelYear,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter Current Level/year"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^([0-9]{3})+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct level and year";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.04,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: matriculationNumber,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText:
                                        "Enter student's matriculation number, use format(RU-CSC-19-202)"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^[A-Z]{2}[-][A-Z]{3}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{3}')
                                          .hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct Matriculation Number";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.04,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: currentSemester,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter current semester"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^[a-z,A-Z]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct name";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.04,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: studentMarks1,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter score for attendance"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct score";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.05,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: studentMarks2,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter score for assignment"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct score";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.05,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: studentMarks3,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter score for test"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct score";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.05,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: studentMarks4,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter Score for exams"),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                      !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                                    return "Enter correct score";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.05,
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                child: Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    width: 500,
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                          style: ButtonStyle(
                                            foregroundColor:
                                                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                                    Colors.black),
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                                    Colors.black),
                                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                                    RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            1000))),
                                          ),
                                          child: Text("Submit", style: kHeading),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                              
                                            
var finalScore = int.parse(
                                                      studentMarks2.text) +
                                                  int.parse(studentMarks3.text) +
                                                  int.parse(studentMarks4.text);
                                              Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                                                "Attendance": studentMarks1.text,
                                                "Assignment": studentMarks2.text,
                                                "Test Score": studentMarks3.text,
                                                "Examination Score":
                                                    studentMarks4.text,
                                                "final score": finalScore
                                              };
                                              final docUser = FirebaseFirestore
                                                  .instance
                                                  .collection("Exam Scores")
                                                  .doc(
                                                      "${currentLevelYear.text} Level")
                                                  .collection(
                                                      matriculationNumber.text)
                                                  .doc(
                                                      "${currentSemester.text} semester")
                                                  .collection(courseCode.text)
                                                  .doc("Scores");
                                              docUser.set(data);
                                            }
                                          }),
                                    )),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 15,
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => Homepage()));
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Go back to home page",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Textformfield will work for you. You just need to check the data type required for the firebase and you can also add a validator in the Textformfield and pass pass regex to it. Textformfield will valid the input data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if you could show some code I would really appreciate it